# open a table after i click a button on react

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am doing a program in react and I want to show a list of permissions after I click the button.
Right now I am showing the information with window.alert but i want to show it on a prettier list.

The button that I press:

[image]

What is showing right now (prints all elements on the list one at the time):

[image]

When i click that butotn i want all the elements of the list to appear on this way:

[image]

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of the react-bootstrap `Popover` and the `ListGroup` components in your render method.

```
const popover = (
  <Popover id="popover-permission" title="Permissions">
    <ListGroup>
      <ListGroup.Item>Permission 1</ListGroup.Item>
      <ListGroup.Item>Permission 2</ListGroup.Item>
      <ListGroup.Item>Permission 3</ListGroup.Item>
    </ListGroup>
  </Popover>
);

return <OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="bottom" overlay={popover}>
  <Button variant="secondary">Show Permissions</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```